# Make certain widget scrollable

Tags: flutter, dart, listview, scroll

I have a Column widget in my page. There are two widget in Column widget, one is ListTie, another is ListView.

```
Widget _showBody(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(children: [
      ListTile(
        horizontalTitleGap: 0,
        tileColor: Colors.white,
        onTap: () {},
        leading: const Icon(
          Icons.smart_button,
        ),
        trailing: const Icon(Icons.arrow_right),
        title: const Text('Click Inside'),
      ),
      BlocConsumer<SmartMeterListScreenCubit, SmartMeterListScreenState>(
          builder: ((context, state) {
            if (state is SmartMeterListScreenDone) {
              return Column(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: [
                    Container(
                        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                        color: Colors.grey.shade200,
                        child: Padding(
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
                            child: Text(
                              "Total items : ${state.smartMeter?.length}",
                              style:
                                  TextStyle(color: Colors.deepPurple.shade900),
                            ))),
                    RefreshIndicator(
                        onRefresh: () async {
                          // function
                        },
                        child: ListView.separated(
                            physics: const AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                            separatorBuilder: (context, index) => Padding(
                                padding:
                                    const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20),
                                child: Container(
                                  color: Colors.grey.shade200,
                                  height: 1,
                                )),
                            padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
                            shrinkWrap: true,
                            itemCount: 100,
                            itemBuilder: (conntext, index) {
                              return InkWell(
                                  onTap: () {},
                                  child: ListItemPadding(
                                      child: Text(index.toString())));
                            }))
                  ]);
            }
            return Container();
          }),
          listener: ((context, state) {}))
    ]);
  }
```

I would like to make the `ListTile` and totalItem text not scrollable , only the `ListView` scrollable.

Here the error

> ════════ Exception caught by rendering library
> ═════════════════════════════════ The following assertion was thrown
> during layout: A RenderFlex overflowed by 4358 pixels on the bottom.
>
> Widget creation tracking is currently disabled. Enabling it enables
> improved error messages. It can be enabled by passing
> `--track-widget-creation` to `flutter run` or `flutter test`. The
> overflowing RenderFlex has an orientation of Axis.vertical. The edge
> of the RenderFlex that is overflowing has been marked in the rendering
> with a yellow and black striped pattern. This is usually caused by the
> contents being too big for the RenderFlex.

I know I can simply fix it by wrapping the parent column with `SingleChildScrollView`,but this will make the whole screen scroll, which is not what I want.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it by adding two `Expanded`.

One is wrapping on `BlocConsumer`, another is wrapping on `RefreshIndicator`.

Answer (score 1):

1. Wrap the ListView in an Expanded widget: This will make the ListView
   take up all the available vertical space in the Column. If the
   ListView has a large number of items and exceeds the screen's
   height, it will become scrollable.
2. Use a SingleChildScrollView: If you want the entire content to be scrollable (both the ListTile and the ListView), you can wrap the
   Column with a SingleChildScrollView. This makes the entire content
   scrollable, including the ListTile.

[image]

Comment: I tried the first option, still getting same error. Second options fixed, but whole screen scrollable, which is not what I want.

Answer (score 0):

Try wrapping your `ListView.separated` widget in an `Expanded` widget.

Comment: tried, but not working